# How to filter sfc polygons by long/lat values?

Tags: r, r-sf

Suppose `t` is:

```
t <- structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(-89.990791, -89.990772, 
-89.990901, -89.99092, -89.990791, 30.727025, 30.727083, 30.727114, 
30.727057, 30.727025), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-89.991691, -89.991755, -89.991755, 
-89.991691, -89.991691, 30.716004, 30.716004, 30.715916, 30.715916, 
30.716004), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"
))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -89.991755, 
ymin = 30.715916, xmax = -89.990772, ymax = 30.727114), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)
> t
Geometry set for 2 features 
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -89.99176 ymin: 30.71592 xmax: -89.99077 ymax: 30.72711
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
POLYGON ((-89.99079 30.72703, -89.99077 30.7270...
POLYGON ((-89.99169 30.716, -89.99175 30.716, -...
```

How can I filter polygons by long/lat boundaries? Suppose I want to filter out any polygon that hax lat>30.72 (so to keep only the second polygon). Is there any specific function I can use to filter polygons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know if there is a ready-made function, but a rectangular “spatial filter”
is easy to build. Just define the “corners”, create a bbox from them, convert
to polygon and find which of your original polygons are contained / overlap
the "filter area".

Here is a quick-and-dirty example:

```r
library(sf)
polys_sf<-st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf") ) %>% 
  st_transform(crs="+init=epsg:4326")
plot(st_geometry(polys_sf))
```

[image]

Define a “spatial filter”

```r
xmin <- -80
xmax <- -76
ymin <- 34
ymax <- 36
```

create a polygon based on the filter. (You can use "NA" for some values, so if you want for example to filter only "on the left", you can set xmax to NA)

```r
filt_bbox <- sf::st_bbox(c(xmin = ifelse(is.na(xmin), -180, xmin), 
                           ymin = ifelse(is.na(ymin),  -90,  ymin), 
                           xmax = ifelse(is.na(xmax), +180, xmax), 
                           ymax = ifelse(is.na(ymax),  +90, ymax)), 
                         crs = st_crs(4326)) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sfc(.)
```

Now "filter" the original dataset based on the bbox polygon: Use `st_within` if you want to keep only the polys completely contained in the defined area

```r
find_data <- sf::st_within(polys_sf, filt_bbox)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_within assumes that they are planar
filt_data <- polys_sf[which(lengths(find_data) != 0), ]

plot(filt_bbox)
plot(st_geometry(filt_data), add = TRUE, reset = FALSE)
```

[image]

Use `st_intersects` if you want to keep all polys that intersect the defined area

```r
find_data <- sf::st_intersects(polys_sf, filt_bbox)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes that they are planar
filt_data <- polys_sf[which(lengths(find_data) != 0), ]

plot(st_geometry(filt_data))
plot(filt_bbox, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

(Clearly, this works if both your polys and the “filtering extent” are lat/long, otherwise
you have to take care of reprojecting, etcetera.)
<sup>Created on 2018-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can do this a lot easier using a simple function:

```
filter_sf <- function(.data, xmin = NULL, xmax = NULL, ymin = NULL, ymax = NULL) {
  bb <- sf::st_bbox(.data)
  if (!is.null(xmin)) bb["xmin"] <- xmin
  if (!is.null(xmax)) bb["xmax"] <- xmax
  if (!is.null(ymin)) bb["ymin"] <- ymin
  if (!is.null(ymax)) bb["ymax"] <- ymax
  sf::st_filter(.data, sf::st_as_sfc(bb), .predicate = sf::st_within)
}
```

So now you can do:

```
t %>%
  filter_sf(ymin = 30.72)
```

This method works for both `POLYGON` and `MULTIPOLYGON` geometries.

Comment: I think the code to call it should be `(ymin = 30.72)`